# Java gui - how to create abstract shapes

Tags: java, user-interface

*Can I create with java awt or something else, an abstract shapes?*

**For example,**

I have a `window` that waiting for user's input. 
The `window's` `shape` is square like the most `windows`.

So I wondered if can I change the `shape` of this `window` let's say to a pic's shape that I created?

Comment: are you want to resize window(square) or want to change whole shape like from square to round or etc ?

Comment: @vishalgajera Exactly, the second option, to change whole shape.

Comment: whole shape mean can i guess from square to round or start ?

Comment: @vishalgajera I want window with shape of some picture. Let's say that the picture with dog's shape. Is it possible?

Comment: Check out [The Java Tutorials - How to Create Translucent and Shaped Windows](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html)

Comment: @VinceEmigh Thank you very match!